# How to create a 45 degree Askew or skew element in objective-c?

Tags: objective-c, uibezierpath, angle, skew, degrees

I want to create any (particularly uiview) kind of element (uiimageview, uibutton, uilabel etc.,) that should be in askew or skew style.

Is that possible in xcode - objective-c?

If you want deep explanation:

1) go to [google.com](http://google.com) and search ASKEW or [click here](https://www.google.com/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=vRsFVrKjJ6vG8AeR1bygBA&gws_rd=ssl#q=askew)

2) like italic fonts

Advance thanks :)

**UPDATED @ 21/12/2015**

I found `uibezierpath` that allow you to draw point to point if anyone know to draw `uibezierpath` add that answer in comment field.

Comment: -1 You give the advice to google for the terms instead of explaining it yourself or give at least a link to an explanation? BTW: What google shows is a rotation and it is *not* like italic fonts. So what do you want?

Comment: Read that question again. If you don't understand what I say then only give you should go with that explanation ( **If you want** deep explanation:) and normal fonts always 90 degree but italic fonts letters like lightly skew that's why I mention that. If you can't understand then read my question once again or Below @Cristiano Alves post a image look that too.

Comment: 1. It is wrong, that normal fonts have degrees of 90°. 2. What @Christiane Alves shows, is *not* like an italic font. It is a rotation. (On italic fonts usually horizontal lines are not rotated.) 3. It is not the task of people answering to explain the Q.

Comment: 1. 90° means for example it's also refer vertical straight line. 2. If @Christiane Alves gives wrong answer guide us for right one - If without rotate a element that show like italic font (vertically 45° and horizontally 180°) - 3. If you don't understand my words or google anything then see that image, that image used for reference to understand.

Comment: 1. I did not say that he gave a wrong answer, I said that it is not clear, what you wanted.  What he did is *not* like an italic font. It is like a rotated font (`CGAffineTransformRotate`). 2. It is not the task of the answerers to explain the Qs.

Comment: Italic fonts are sheared: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shear_mapping. (No, it is much more complex, but at least this is a drop of truth in your Q.)

Comment: @Christiane Alves answer rotate a view give like italic (shear like that name whatever) look. Yes, that wiki link is exactly what I want. Here everyone want to share their knowledge If you see irrelevant answers for that question and if you know correct answer, then share it here else....

Comment: What Cristiano's views shows is *not* what's described in the wiki link. You still cannot say, what you want: rotation (Cristiano) or shearing (italic font).I really do not know how I can explain to you that rotation and shearing are *two different* things. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transformation_matrix#Rotation

Comment: Yes, I want shape like shearing and I know that different between rotation and shearing. I don't have any other answer meet my requirement. If anyone post a answer that look like shearing then I will change accept answer. I need to do add a horizontal view(with White bg color) it's look like shearing. Thanks for your involvement to show different between shearing and rotation.

Comment: Well, I asked you 4 days long, whether you want shearing or rotation. After 4 days asking you say that you know the difference and give an answer. After 4 days marking a "rotation" answer as correct, you  say that you want shearing instead. Man! However, instead of using `CGAffineTransformRotate()` you have to use `CGAffineTransformMake()` and set the values you can get from my wiki-link.

Comment: I am new bee for programming also objective C. Below answer is not what I ask but that answer at-least that's meet my requirement some what. As I said before "If anyone post a answer that look like shearing then I will change accept answer". I don't know what's make different with that for I am accept answer? Okay I will try with CGAffineTransformMake(). Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

You can have this view inside a askew view like this:

```
UIView *askewView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds];

UIView *exampleView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100, 100, 100, 100)];

exampleView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];

[askewView addSubview:exampleView];

askewView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

[self.view addSubview:askewView];

CGAffineTransform transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(askewView.transform, 0.1);//M_PI/4);

askewView.transform = transform;
```

I used 0.1 radians because I think that 45º is to much, but in comment have the PI/4 (45º).

Result:

[image]

I hope this can help you.

Comment: Thank you :)
**comment have the PI/4 (45º)** little explanation more about this?

Comment: In transform you need put the value in radians. If you want 120 degrees you have put  2.09 radians. Google can convert [this](https://www.google.pt/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=120+degrees+to+radians)

Comment: PI/4 radians = 45 degrees

Comment: I just remove your answer because of I found that little help to make shape like that `uibezierpath` If you know that explane about that how can I use that. :(